# SDL & OpenGL - Artifacts when multisampling

Tags: opengl, sdl

Im trying to render a model with anialiasing using OpenGL and SDL, but when I do I get strange artifacts.

When I render with antialiasing disabled everything looks fine.
[image: Aliasing]

When antialiasing is enabled I get white dots in edges of the model.
[image: AntiAliasing]

I'm using a Nvidia Geforce 320M graphics card and enabling the display as well as the multisampling with this code

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 4);
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

This is the fragment shader:

```
#version 330

#define MAX_NUM_LIGHTS 4

in vec3 normal0;
in vec3 pos;

out vec4 FragColor;

struct LightSource
{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 ambientColor;
    vec4 diffuseColor;
    vec4 specularColor;

    // attenuation parameters
    float attConstant;
    float attLinear;
    float attQuadratic;
};

struct Material
{
    vec4 ambientColor;
    vec4 diffuseColor;
    vec4 specularColor;
    float shininess;
};

uniform LightSource light[MAX_NUM_LIGHTS];
uniform Material material;
uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform int numOfLights;

// function declarations
vec4 calcDirLight(LightSource light, Material material, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDirection);
vec4 calcPointLight(LightSource light, Material material, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDirection);

void main()
{
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize( viewPos - pos );
    vec4 result = vec4(0.0f);

    // Loop over all lights
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfLights; i++)
    {
        // Directional light
        if( light[i].position.w == 0.0f )
        {
            result += calcDirLight( light[i], material, normal0, viewDirection);
        }
        // Point light
        else if ( light[i].position.w == 1.0f )
        {
            result += calcPointLight( light[i], material, normal0, pos, viewDirection);
        }
    }

    FragColor = result;
}

vec4 calcDirLight(LightSource light, Material material, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDirection)
{
    // Properties
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize( vec3(light.position) );
    vec3 reflectDirection = reflect( -lightDirection, normal);

    // Ambient component
    vec4 ambientComponent = light.ambientColor * material.ambientColor;

    // Diffuse component
    float diffuseReflection = clamp(dot(normal,lightDirection), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseComponent = diffuseReflection * light.diffuseColor * material.diffuseColor;

    // Specular component
    float specularReflection = pow( max( dot( viewDirection,reflectDirection ), 0.0 ), material.shininess );
    vec4 specularComponent = specularReflection * light.specularColor * material.specularColor;

    return ( ambientComponent + diffuseComponent + specularComponent);
}

vec4  calcPointLight(LightSource light, Material material, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDirection)
{
    // Properties
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize( vec3(light.position) - fragPos );
    vec3 reflectDirection = reflect( -lightDirection, normal);
    float distance = length( vec3(light.position) - fragPos );
    float attenuation = 1.0f / ( light.attConstant + (light.attLinear * distance) + (light.attQuadratic * (distance * distance)) );

    // Ambient component
    vec4 ambientComponent = light.ambientColor * material.ambientColor * attenuation;

    // Diffuse component
    float diffuseReflection = clamp(dot(normal,lightDirection), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseComponent = diffuseReflection * light.diffuseColor * material.diffuseColor * attenuation;

    // Specular component
    float specularReflection = pow( max( dot( viewDirection,reflectDirection ), 0.0 ), material.shininess );
    vec4 specularComponent = specularReflection * light.specularColor * material.specularColor * attenuation;

    return ( ambientComponent + diffuseComponent + specularComponent);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what might be the problem?

Comment: I'd like to see your fragment shader code. I think it appears because in some samples the specular calculation blows up.

Comment: @akaltar There, fragment shader present :) (I'm new to SE so I'm unsure if you get a notification of the edit by itself)

Comment: I see no problem with your shader. Did this occur with other test models? for example a box? If you move closer will they become more apparent, or stay at one-pixel size?
Could this be appearing in the non-multisampled version just perhaps at a lower rate? Which type of lights cause this?

Comment: @akaltar This has occurred with other complex models as well. I'm not able to get to my computer right now but I'll check that out your questions as soon as I can.

Comment: Centroid attribute interpolation may help. Aliasing of specular highlights is a huge issue with MSAA, because the fragment shader is generally only evaluated once for each pixel instead of each sample. You get improved edge anti-aliasing but no improvements to (and possibly worse) aliasing on textures and specular highlights. There's [a GL extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sample_shading.txt) that lets you increase the number of samples shaded, which you might look into.

Comment: By the way, you didn't enable `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH`, did you? That is deprecated, so I doubt it, but that is one thing that will cause _exactly_ this problem.

Comment: @akaltar It seems there are no artifacts for a box but there is as soon as a more complex model is loaded. The artifacts are always 1 pixel in size no matter the distance and it doesn't appear for a non-MSAA rendering. After messing around in the fragment shader it's quite clear that the calculation of the speculation reflection is the reason, although I'm not sure why. It seems like both directional lights and point lights give the artifacts but I need to go through my lighting code just to make sure.

Comment: @andonmcoleman I haven't enabled GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH so it's not that but I'll sit down and try your suggestions.

Comment: @Kaitlabben I would experiment with shapes to determine what exactly causes these artifacts. Does it appear on a sphere? a Cone? and find that edge case, maybe you can test for it in the shader somehow or clamp something. In fact maybe you could just clamp SpecularReflection to a max of 1.0 or 2.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman It seems centroid interpolation fixes the issue. Though, is it considered a viable solution or just a hacky one? Everything is rendered nicely now so if it's considered to be viable I might stick with it.

Comment: @akaltar I tried clamping the specular calculation but that only lowered the intensity of the artifacts, they were still there. I might play around later with different models to see just when the problem starts. Anyway, thank you both for the help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Kaitlabben I think I just found your problem: You are not normalizing your input normal. Those small differences may be the culprits. Also explains why centroid interpolation works.

Comment: @akaltar The normals are normalized in the vertex shader and passed to the fragment shader. Does it make a difference if i normalize them  in the fragment shader instead? They are multiplied with a normal matrix and them normalized like so: `normal0 = normalize( (norm * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz );`. The matrix `norm` is the transpose of the inverse upper left 3x3 model matrix (ex-gl_NormalMatrix).

Comment: @Kaitlabben I remember reading it somewhere that interpolating between normalized vectors doesn't lead to normalized vectors, so you should renormalize.(because its a lerp, you could use slerp for more precision). This might not solve your problem but is still an error technically speaking.
Finally if you found the answer being centroid interpolation, then please post an answer about it.

Comment: @akaltar Why normalizing normal vector in vertex shader doesn't suffice? I had exactly the same problem and normalizing solved it, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @patryk.beza Because normals are interpolated over the triangle component-wise when transferred from vertex to fragment shader, their lengths may change, which messes with the way we use their unit-length properties. Using centroid interpolation(I guess) solves this, because it is a type of interpolation that keeps length while interpolating.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out to me, normalizing normals in the vertex shader and then passing them to the fragment shader doesn't ensure they are normalized after being passed. By only passing the normals in the vertex shader and then normalizing them in the fragment shader the problem was fixed.

Another way to fix the error is centroid attribute interpolation between the vertex and fragment shader. This might only be considered a quick-fix however, since the real issue was not normalizing the normals in the fragment shader.